# How to execute a shell command in lua without return value

Tags: shell, lua, luci

how to execute this shell script

```
command = SCRIPT_PATH.."/R.sh "..rfu_path..rfu_file_name.." &"
io.popen(command)
```

without return value?

I want to execute this shell script first. After I called this script it will runs background and my lua code move to next line.
Is it possible?

Comment: is io.popen  work in bash ?

Comment: Use `os.execute` instead of `io.popen`?

Comment: ``os.execute("(sleep 3 && echo 'Sleeped 3 seconds') &")``